# lightning:fileCard No Preview Available or What permissions am I missing?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, files, contentdocument

Here's my code:

```
<lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small">
    <lightning:fileCard fileId="069XXXXXXXXXXXX" description="logo"/>
</lightning:layoutItem>
```

I'm using (for now) a hardcoded Id of a ContentDocument that I know exists, but all I get is a box with `No preview available` in it.
The lightning component sits on the Community Builder page on a site.
The file itself is visible to `Your Company`. The person trying to view this image is logged in as a community user.
There's obviously some configuration I'm missing, but dammit Jim, I'm a developer, not an administrator.
The ContentDocument I'm trying to view here has a ContentDocumentLink with `Visibility=AllUsers` and `LinkedEntityId=00DXXXXXXXXXXXX`.
Doesn't that mean that the file is shared with the entire org? All of the users in the org? Including community users?

Comment: [The person trying to view this image is logged in as a community user] -- Does the Community User have the access to the File?

Comment: @JayantDas from what I can tell, yes. But I'm obviously missing something, I just don't know what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it turns out that this is some kind of "feature" of Salesforce.
Any file created before a community exists cannot be shared with the community. That's just the way it is. And my file is older than the community.
However, any file that is created after the community exists and is shared with the entire org (ContentDocumentLink with `Visibility=AllUsers` and `LinkedEntityId=00DXXXXXXXXXXXX`) will be visible to community users.
So I uploaded a new file and tried that in the `lightning:fileCard` and that worked.
[Knowledge Article.](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000271156&language=en_US&type=1)

Comment: It is saving as LinkedEntityId=005XXXXXXXXXXX for files uploaded after community setup. Is there any other setting I need to do to make LinkedEntityId=00DXXXXXXXXX so that file will be shared to community users as well.

Comment: I did using code on the controller. Since this is the only way for our community members to upload documents, whenever they upload a document my code shares it with the org.

Answer (score 0):

Is this problem occur due to User License?
As the Customer Community Login License don't allows for Content availability for files. 
Refer the document:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&type=5